# Python RE question - proper state initial formatting

Tags: python

I have a string that I need to edit, it looks something similar to this:

```
string = "Idaho Ave N,,Crystal,Mn,55427-1463,US,,610839124763,Expedited"
```

If you notice the state initial "Mn" is not in proper formatting. I'm trying to use a regular expression to change this:

```
re.sub("[A-Z][a-z],", "[A-Z][A-Z],", string)
```

However, re.sub treats the second part as a literal and will change Mn, to [A-Z][A-Z],. How would I use re.sub (or something similar and simple) to properly change Mn, to MN, in this string?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a function as the replacement parameter to `re.sub` to generate the replacement string from the match object, e.g.:

```
import re

s = "Idaho Ave N,,Crystal,Mn,55427-1463,US,,610839124763,Expedited"

def upcase(match):
    return match.group().upper()

print re.sub("[A-Z][a-z],", upcase, s)
```

(This is ignoring the concern of whether you're genuinely finding state initials with this method.)

The appropriate documentation for `re.sub` is [here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub).

Comment: This is very similar to something that I had in mind, thank you and thank you all for your responses.

Answer (score 2):

Your `re.sub` might modify also parts of the string you would not want to modify. Try to process the right element in your list explicitly:

```
input = "Idaho Ave N,,Crystal,Mn,55427-1463,US,,610839124763,Expedited"
elems = input.split(',')
elems[3] = elems[3].upper()
output = ','.join(elems)
```

returns

```
'Idaho Ave N,,Crystal,MN,55427-1463,US,,610839124763,Expedited'
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0)
> ```
>
> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost
>   non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in string by the
>   replacement repl.  repl can be either a string or a callable;
>   if a string, backslash escapes in it are processed.  If it is
>   a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
>   a replacement string to be used.

```
re.sub("[A-Z][a-z]", lambda m: m.group(0).upper(), myString)
```

I would avoid calling your variable `string` since that is a type name.

Answer (score -1):

You create a group by surrounding it in parentheses withing your regex, then refer to is by its group number:

```
re.sub("([A-Z][a-z]),", "\1,".upper(), string)
```

Comment: Calling `upper()` before the substitution starts isn't productive.